# How to continue the test Execution after failing by assertion

Tags: java, api, selenium-webdriver, testng, rest-assured

```java
response = res.when().post(a.getGetBankAPI()).then().extract()
    .response();

//Thread.sleep(1000);
int statuscode = response.getStatusCode();
System.out.println(statuscode);

try {
    Assert.assertEquals(statuscode, 200);
} catch (AssertionError e) {
    org.testng.Assert.fail("Actual value is not equal to Expected value for");
}

System.out.println(getJsonPath(response, "error.message[0].msg"));
assertEqual(getJsonPath(response, "error.message[0].msg"), "branch should be 3 to 50 character long", "Error for passing Empty Branch");
```

Here I the test case is failing after the step print ln status code, but it was not mentioning as failed but it was simply skipping and total test execution is aborted here, if u usr printstacktrace(), it was not skipping but it was also not noted as failure

Answer (score 0):

```
     try
     {
         Assert.assertEquals(statuscode, 200);
     }
     catch(AssertionError e)
     {
         org.testng.Assert.fail("Actual value is not equal to Expected value for");
     }
```

The way you handled by using the try and catch block possibly caused the issue of the test being skipped instead of failed.

It's not good practice to use try catch on assertion. But if you really need this then you can use it like this

```
catch(AssertionError e)
{
    throw new AssertionError("Actual value is not equal to Expected value for", e);
}
```

**If you are using TestNg then you can use assertion in this way. So you do not need to use any try catch to print the message**

```
  Assert.assertEquals("Actual","expected"," Actual result is not same as expected");
```

Comment: I have used Assertequals but at that step it was skipping total execution not running remaining test cases

Comment: Do you want to execute test cases event assertion failed?

Comment: If you want to execute test cases event failed in assertion then use 

softAssert.assertEquals("Hello", "Hello", "First soft assert failed");

Comment: Here is different type of assertion
https://www.toolsqa.com/testng/testng-asserts/

Comment: yes i used soft assert but , in report it wont mentioning it as failed

Comment: this is console output , see after printing status code it is skipping

Comment: Body:
{
    "bank": "hood",
    "branch": "",
    "accountName": "TEST hood",
    "accountNumber": "627265377"
}
422

Comment: actually test case is skipping not failed and all other testcases also skipping

Answer (score 0):

What you need is actually `soft asserts`. TestNG supports such type of asserts so here is an example:

```java
@Test
public void softAssertDemo{
  SoftAssert assertions = new SoftAssert(); // Here you'll be collecting your failures
  assertions.assertTrue(false, "Failure 1");  // Do your regular asserts in this way
  assertions.assertTrue(true, "Pass");
  assertions.assertTrue(false, "Failure 2");
  assertions.assertAll(); // in the end call this to fail your test if there were the faliures
}
```